# How to display only part of text of selected option in ng select input field?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ngselect

I am using ng select to display the options text that consist of first name and last name. I want to display only the first name in the input field on selecting the option.

I have tried to set the value as first name. So I receive the first name in the model. But It displays the full name in the ng select input field. How to only show the first name here.

[Below Image show the current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cf5w.png)

Please refer the initial code that I have written.

```
 <ng-select placeholder="{{ 'LOCAL_CONNECTOR_DIALOG.ENTER_NAME' | translate }}"
             [(ngModel)]="currentUserfirstName">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let person of persons"
               [value]="person.firstName">{{person.fullName()}}</ng-option>
  </ng-select>
```

Comment: change [value]="person.firstName">{{person.fullName()}} to  [value]="person.firstName">{{person.firstName}}

Comment: @Walter If I make this change, then this will display only first name in options also. My requirement is to show full name in options but when I select it should only first name in ng select input.

Answer (score 0):

You should use firstName as displayed name of option

```
<ng-select placeholder="{{ 'LOCAL_CONNECTOR_DIALOG.ENTER_NAME' | translate }}"
             [(ngModel)]="currentUserfirstName">
    <ng-option *ngFor="let person of persons"
               [value]="person.firstName">{{person.firstName}}</ng-option>
  </ng-select>
```

Comment: But my requirement is to display both first name and last name in options display. Is there any way to make it different from what will be diplayed in selected input?